# Update Syntax and Passing Strings

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running into an issue while using the Update syntax when updating a table row with a string. I'll post the code below then explain my issue:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = '$id'";
$results = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($results);
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j) {
    $entity_id=mysql_result($results,$j,'entity_id');
}

//$entity_id = "129";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
        $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']); 
        $query = "UPDATE field_data_body SET body_value='$text' WHERE entity_id='$entity_id'";
        mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database' . mysql_error());
    }

?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <textarea name="comments">Example Comment</textarea>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Here's a quick rundown of what the code does. I first request for the value of $entity_id from the table foo. I then update a different table row using a text-area and submit button.

My issue lies on line 12:

```
$query = "UPDATE field_data_body SET body_value='$text' WHERE entity_id='$entity_id'";
```

If $entity_id is passed directly to this line, the row will not update. If I assign an integer to $entity_id, (line 8 without the comment), the row will update. I've checked to make sure $entity_id is assigned a value before it gets to the submit section of the script; it returns 129, (echo "$entity_id"; output is 129). Why can I not pass the string without having to assign an integer?

EDIT: I found where the issue was taking place. The issue was on line 18, where the action attribute is called. I removed the php, and replaced it with a #. I'm not entirely sure why this was a fix to the problem, but there you have it. Thanks to those below with their suggestions and help, I do appreciate it!

Comment: Replace WHERE entity_id='$entity_id' with WHERE entity_id=$entity_id as you don't want the parameter to be treated as text.

Comment: Your `entity_id` returned by the db (probably) is an int. When you do `$entity_id = "129";` you are assigning a string to it. As @JA mentioned try changing the way you are treating the quotes. Also you should update to mysqli or PDO, and you are vulnerable to sql injection. Read http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: I'm get a syntax error when I remove the single quotes: Error updating databaseYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: The `for` loop makes no sense. You're just setting `$entity_id` from the last row of results, you're ignoring all the other rows.

Comment: What does `echo $query` show?

Comment: I've removed other queries within the for loop for the purpose of this question, I request other values as well. echo $query returns nothing. I'm not sure why that is the case.

Comment: That makes no sense. You put the `echo` right after the assignment?

Comment: the quotes around `$entity_id` shouldn't make a difference, MySQL will automatically convert a string to a number when necessary.

Comment: Yes echo $entity_id; is after the assignment. I'm confused as you are about this..

Comment: Talking about `echo $query`, not `echo $entity_id`.

Comment: Sorry, yes echo $query is below the assignment and returns an empty string.